# Error 105, press F5 on Safari using Sierra

Tags: macos, safari

Since update to macOS Sierra I have permanent error while trying to watch movie on the ewebsite:

[image]

**Do you know how to solve this?**

Comment: I'd suggest you contact the owner of that website. That's an error in their video player, not in Safari or macOS.

Comment: Google says that's a DNS error - name not resolved. It also only seems to come up with Polish language queries, which would maybe suggest some kind of border control. Maybe try a different DNS provider, Google or OpenDNS

Comment: What does it mean to try different provider? Another web browser?

Comment: DNS provider - your usual one will be your ISP's own DNS, which is usually the simplest to use. System prefs > Network > [connection type] > Advanced... > DNS. Try putting 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in there instead of your ISP's address [click + & you can replace the existing address, you can't delete the only address] Might need a reboot to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change your wifi setting. Change **Configure iPv6** to `Link-local only`

[image]

Comment: You should do that anyway if your ISP isn't yet providing IPv6